# Image is getting pushed outside of the div its wrapped in

Tags: javascript, html, css

Nobel Prize to the person who can figure out why the second image is pushed outside the div its wrapped in.

I thought that what I did was pretty straightforward:

```
<div class="outerdiv" id="headerbox">
    <div id="uwlogo">
        <img src="uwlogo.png" height="50px"\>
    </div>
    <div id="JaminWEB">
        <h1>JaminWEB</h1>
    </div>  
    <div id="rainer">
        <img src="rainer.jpg" height="50px"\>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the corresponding stylesheet code

```
#uwlogo
{
    float: left;
}

#JaminWEB
{
    float: center;
}
#rainer
{
    float: right;
}
h1
{
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
}
```

JFiddle link, since I know someone will request one: http://jsfiddle.net/u7PJj/

Comment: use text-align: center; instead of float:center;

Comment: you have mentioned the wrong closing tag which might be an issue, try the below format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer why it's happening is a number of things:

1. float: center is not valid so it's not floating
2. Your #JaminWeb is taking up 100% width thus forcing your third floating (rainer) element to wrap and float right (on the next line)
3. Your headerBox is set to height of 50px and float does not change those dimensions, so it appears to be floating outside of its container.

To fix it I suggest going with absolute positioning instead of floating.  This way your JaimenWEB div can be centered and take full width and the logos get placed around it.

```
#headerbox
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
#uwlogo
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}

#JaminWEB
{
    text-align: center;
}
#rainer
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

I've updated your fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/u7PJj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<div id="uwlogo">
        <img src="uwlogo.png" height="50px" />
    </div>
<div id="rainer">
        <img src="rainer.jpg" height="50px" />
    </div>
<div id="JaminWEB">
        <h1>JaminWEB</h1>
    </div>
```